# Argument to function

Tags: c, function, pointers, arguments, structure

I am confused by this argument to the function which is defined as

```
int bind(int s, const struct sockaddr *name, int namelen)
```

and called as

```
bind(sd, (struct sockaddr_in *) &addr, length);
```

I'm unable to interpret what `struct sockaddr_in *` means here.

Would this work: `bind (sd, &addr, length);`?

Comment: The call would provoke a warning.

Comment: ok then how `struct sockaddr_in *` is avoiding it?
i`ve never sen such argument before, so I am not getting what exactly it is doing.

Comment: ' struct sockaddr_in *' provokes the warning. It should be ' struct sockaddr *'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be called like this:

```
bind (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, length);
```

As for why, this is the C way of doing [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming), if you look at the definitions of those structures:

```
struct sockaddr {
    unsigned short    sa_family;    // address family, AF_xxx
    char              sa_data[14];  // 14 bytes of protocol address
};

// IPv4 AF_INET sockets:
struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;   // e.g. AF_INET, AF_INET6
    unsigned short   sin_port;     // e.g. htons(3490)
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;     // see struct in_addr, below
    char             sin_zero[8];  // zero this if you want to
};

// IPv6 AF_INET6 sockets:
struct sockaddr_in6 {
    u_int16_t       sin6_family;   // address family, AF_INET6
    u_int16_t       sin6_port;     // port number, Network Byte Order
    u_int32_t       sin6_flowinfo; // IPv6 flow information
    struct in6_addr sin6_addr;     // IPv6 address
    u_int32_t       sin6_scope_id; // Scope ID
};
```

They all share the same first member, `sa_family` when you pass a pointer to one of those structures to `bind()` you first cast it to `struct sockaddr *` and inside the function, `sa_family` is used to determine which structure you passed and cast back to the right one, instead of having one function for each structure you have one function that accepts `sockaddr*`.

Another way to look at it, from an OOP perspective, imagine that `sockaddr` is the base class for `sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr_in6`, and passing a pointer to `sockaddr` is similar to casting to the base type and calling a generic function. hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: this was descriptive, understood the need of typecasting here, thank you.
`man bind` presented just example but i couldn`t find structure definition.

Answer (score 2):

Except with `void` pointers, conversion from a pointer to `T` to a pointer to `U` should be explicit.

```
bind (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, length);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what `addr` is.

If it's not the address of same struct then you need to typecast it,Other wise you will get warning that implicit typecast from `<type of addr>` to `const struct sockaddr*`

To see the all warning messages given by compiler in compilation of any program.
start using this (for compiler `gcc` warnings ):

`gcc -Wall <test.c> -o <test>`

It's the best practice for programmers.